# Find match in callback string - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to find an exact match in a callback string. Let's say I want to find `c` in the callback string `a,b,c,d,e,`. How do I find `c` in the callback string so I can check if it exists? Example code...

**This is the string from the callback**

```
a,b,c,d,e,
```

This is to validate if string contains the letter `c`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: Data,
    success: function(myhtml){
        // Find exact word that contains 'c'
        var string = $(""+myhtml+":contains('c')");
        if (string) {
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what is in the return of myhtml?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method to check if the string exists within another. This method returns -1 if it doesn't.

```
if( myhtml.indexOf('c') !== -1 ){
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain javascript:

```
var found = myhtml.toLowerCase().indexOf("c") >= 0;
if (found)
{
   // ...
}
```

---

[JavaScript indexOf() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a
>   specified value in a string. 
>   This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

Comment: Also you might find useful `lastIndexOf()` method

Comment: How is this different/better from the examples above?